# How to associate models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application there are two models User and Event. I want to associate two models such that one user can create only single event but can login to many events created by the others users.

I have tried the below association but its not working for me

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :user
end
```

How do I associate two models in above condition.

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to do this with associations alone. You will need extra code to manipulate the associations....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those relationships refer to the underlying database structure.

When you say `belongs_to :event`, Rails will look for a column called `event_id` on the `users` table. You're telling it that there is one event for every user and the user will store which event it is associated with.

When you write `has_one :event`, Rails will look for a column called `user_id` on the `events` table in the database. You're telling it that there is one event per user and that the event model is responsible for holding which user it is associate with.

If you want the user to only create one event and have each event belong to a user, then you would want the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

If you want users to be able to attend multiple events, you'll want a separate table that holds just that information.

```
class EventRegistration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You would then add a new row to the `event_registrations` table for each event you wanted to connect with a given user. This table would be referred to as a join table, since its primary purpose is to create a relationship between records in other tables (which is what a SQL `JOIN` statement does.)

Comment: You should use has_and_belongs_to_many for attendee relationship. Checkout this docs for it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: @JakeKaad I avoid that in all production applications. HABTM abstracts away an entire table, which is almost never what I want. Eventually your join table ends up with logic or its own data. You want to deal with it directly.